# BeautifulSoup remove tag attributes and text contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to compare some webpages based on their overall DOM structure but not their particular contents. To this end i need a representation that resembles the tag hierachy but does not include attributes or textual tag-contents.

Basically, I want to turn a representation like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="peter">My First Heading</h1>
<p><span style="color:red">My</span> first paragraph.</p>

<img src="peter.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

into a canoncial baremetal representation like this:

`<html><body><h1></h1><p><span></span></p><img/></body></html>`

i.e. all attributes removed, as well as tag contents that are not other tags.

I found a way to remove attributes from tags, but im having problems differentiation between text child nodes and tag child nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) say,

> You can’t edit a string in place, but you can replace one string with another, using replace_with()

so I would go for something like this (assume `soup` is exactly what you posted):

```
for e in soup.find_all(True):
    e.attrs = {}

    for i in e.contents:
        if i.string:
            i.string.replace_with('')
```

I think without looping into each tag's content you'll end up with some text leftovers in cases in which a tag has more than one child and one of them is text and another one is another tag containing text (as in your example `<p><span style="color:red">My</span> first paragraph.</p>`).

When run against your example:

```
(env) $ python strip.py                                                               
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><body><h1></h1><p><span></span></p><img/></body></html>
```

(it can be changed a little so it doesn't return newlines or doctype)