# Flatten HTML code, with tree structure delimiters

Tags: python, html, dom, beautifulsoup, tree

I have some raw HTML scraped from a random website, possibly messy, with some scripts, self-closing tags, etc. Example:

```
ex="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \\\n><html lang=\\'en-US\\'><head><meta http-equiv=\\'Content-Type\\'/><title>Some text</title></head><body><h1>Some other text</h1><p><span style='color:red'>My</span> first paragraph.</p></body></html>"
```

I want to return the HTML DOM without any string, attributes or such stuff, only the tag structure, in the format of a string showing the relation between parents, children and siblings, this would be my **expected output** (though the use of brackets is a personnal choice):

```
'[html[head[meta, title], body[h1, p[span]]]]'
```

So far I tried using beautifulSoup (this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904190/3871924) was helpful). I figured out I should split the work in two steps: 
- extract the tag "skeleton" of the html DOM, emptying everything like strings, attributes, and stuff before the `<html>`.
- return the flat HTML DOM, but structured with tree-like delimiters indicating each children and siblings, such as brackets.
I posted the code as an self-answer

Comment: i'll be glad to have some feedback about the downvotes :-) tried to reformulate the question twice already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion. The [name](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-name-argument) argument will give the name of the tag. You can check if the type is `bs4.element.Tag` to confirm if an element is a tag.

```
import bs4
ex="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \\\n><html lang=\\'en-US\\'><head><meta http-equiv=\\'Content-Type\\'/><title>Some text</title></head><body><h1>Some other text</h1><p><span style='color:red'>My</span> first paragraph.</p></body></html>"
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(ex,'html.parser')
str=''
def recursive_child_seach(tag):
    global str
    str+=tag.name
    child_tag_list=[x for x in tag.children if type(x)==bs4.element.Tag]
    if len(child_tag_list) > 0:
        str+='['
    for i,child in enumerate(child_tag_list):
        recursive_child_seach(child)
        if not i == len(child_tag_list) - 1: #if not last child
            str+=', '
    if len(child_tag_list) > 0:
        str+=']'
    return
recursive_child_seach(soup.find())
print(str)
#html[head[meta, title], body[h1, p[span]]]
print('['+str+']')
#[html[head[meta, title], body[h1, p[span]]]]
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, much more elegant than mine! creating the final string within the recursion is clever.

Answer (score 0):

I post here my first solution, which is still a bit messy and uses a lot of regex. The first function gets the emptied DOM structure and outputs it as a raw string, the second function modifies the string to add the delimiters.

```
import re
def clear_tags(htmlstring, remove_scripts=False):
    htmlstring = re.sub("^.*?(<html)",r"\1", htmlstring, flags=re.DOTALL)
    finishyoursoup = soup(htmlstring, 'html.parser')
    for tag in finishyoursoup.find_all():
        tag.attrs = {}
        for sub in tag.contents:
            if sub.string:
                sub.string.replace_with('')
    if remove_scripts:
        [tag.extract() for tag in finishyoursoup.find_all(['script', 'noscript'])]
    return(str(finishyoursoup))
clear_tags(ex)
# '<html><head><meta/><title></title></head><body><h1></h1><p><span></span></p></b
def flattened_html(htmlstring):
    import re
    squeletton = clear_tags(htmlstring)
    step1      = re.sub("<([^/]*?)>", r"[\1",  squeletton) # replace begining of tag
    step2      = re.sub("</(.*?)>",   r"]",    step1) # replace end of tag
    step3      = re.sub("<(.*?)/>",   r"[\1]", step2) # deal with self-closing tag
    step4      = re.sub("\]\[",       ", ",    step3) # gather sibling tags with coma
    return(step4)
flattened_html(ex)
# '[html[head[meta, title], body[h1, p[span]]]]'
```