# With Beautiful soup regular expression need to replace attribute along with its element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to replace "<b'span' b'mcid'="b'0'">" element with "p" tag. Able to search only b'span but not its attribute and value b'mcid'="b'0'" to be replaced with "p" tag. Only b'span tag is getting replace and not its attribute.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile('^b\'span\'')):
    tag.name = 'p'
print(soup.prettify())

htmldata

<body>
 <page bbox="0.000,0.000,594.000,792.000" id="0" rotate="0">
  <b'span' b'mcid'="b'0'">
   Text Text Text.
  </b'span'>
  <b'span' b'mcid'="b'1'">
   Text Text Text
  </b'span'>
  <b'span' b'mcid'="b'2'">
   Edition 1.0, November 2006
  </b'span'>
</body>

Current Output with above mentioned code is:

<body>
 <page bbox="0.000,0.000,594.000,792.000" id="0" rotate="0">
  <p b'mcid'="b'0'">
   Text Text Text
  </p>
  <p b'mcid'="b'1'">
   Text Text Text
  </p>
  <p b'mcid'="b'2'">
   Edition 1.0, November 2006
  </p>
</body>

Required Output: Attribute also need to be searched and replaced

<body>
 <page bbox="0.000,0.000,594.000,792.000" id="0" rotate="0">
  <p>
   Text Text Text
  </p>
  <p>
   Text Text Text
  </p>
  <p>
   Edition 1.0, November 2006
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup remove tag attributes and text contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901940/beautifulsoup-remove-tag-attributes-and-text-contents)

Answer (score 1):

You might be confused of the concept of `tag` and `attribute` in the html. You don't replace an attribute with a tag. You replaced the `<b'span>` tag with `<p>`, and now you need to remove the attributes of that tag (not replace the attribute with tag). Try this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



htmldata = '''<body>
 <page bbox="0.000,0.000,594.000,792.000" id="0" rotate="0">
  <b'span' b'mcid'="b'0'">
   Text Text Text.
  </b'span'>
  <b'span' b'mcid'="b'1'">
   Text Text Text
  </b'span'>
  <b'span' b'mcid'="b'2'">
   Edition 1.0, November 2006
  </b'span'>
</body>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile('^b\'span\'')):
    tag.name = 'p'
    tag.attrs = None
print(soup.prettify())
```

**Output:**

```
<body>
 <page bbox="0.000,0.000,594.000,792.000" id="0" rotate="0">
  <p>
   Text Text Text.
  </p>
  <p>
   Text Text Text
  </p>
  <p>
   Edition 1.0, November 2006
  </p>
 </page>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem and thanks for quick response which is very much appreciated. However i wanted to solve in different manner where i was looking to search entire element and its attributed in one go <b'span' b'mcid'="b'0'">, <b'span' b'mcid'="b'1"> as these are incremental elements which are in thousands.  After searching entire element using regex in beautiful soup i wanted to replace with <p>. Not as a separate element and attribute.  I was reading many links on beautiful soup regarding replacement of attributes but didn't find Attrs=None but it works. Thanks a lot.